# flutter gradle error, how can i solve it?

Tags: android, flutter

so I was trying to use firebase in this app and I got this problem with Gradle stuff...anyone knows how to solve it?...

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

so it is giving me the error in the buildscript option up there, and also telling me abour problems with 'android' and 'app' things, this is the
specific message:

"The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: Could you edit this question so that the code and error are in a codeblock so that we can easily copy and read it?

Comment: ok bro I'll do it wait

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's already up bro, thanks for waiting

Answer (score 0):

**Google-services above 4.2.0 is not available at mavenCentral**. Change your `buildscript` and `allprojects` blocks like this and please try again.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        //  Add this to your project 
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

If this does not solve your problem, it may be due to the fact that your gradle file is corrupted. Download `gradle` file and try again.